# Можно в Рабочую (не тестовую) версию приложения вставить тестовый баннер AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

Можно в Рабочую (уже не тестовую: не бета и не альфа) версию приложения вставить тестовый баннер AdMob? Или сразу нужно вставлять не тестовый баннер?

Comment: На время разработки или в релиз с тестовым хотите выйти?

Comment: Временно в релиз!... Боюсь из-за возможных ошибок вставлять рабочий AdMob баннер в приложение, т.к. слышал, что за не правильное обращение с которым - 
очень жесткие санкции к разработчикам! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно. Можно сам баннер вставить, но не отображать, чтобы не портить внешний вид.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Это делается двумя способами:

а) Вставить активность AdMob'а в нужном месте (к примеру, посмотрел видео - получил дополнительный бонус).

б) Загрузить готовый .apk на сервер AdMob, указав учётные данные, карту и т. д. Реклама будет появляться сама каждые N минут (т. е. время задаёте сами).